# Moving Colobox.js captions to top of box?

Tags: jquery, colorbox

I am trying to move colorbox.js's captions (title attribute text) to the top of the box - it defaults to the bottom. I can't see where to do it in the js - though other mods have been pretty easy.

I'm sure it is simple, if it is doable.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to adjust it in the styles. In the following demo page of the colorbox examples, when clicking on the first example:

Change `#cboxLoadedContent{margin-bottom: 28px;}` to `#cboxLoadedContent{margin-top: 28px;}`
Add `top:0;` to the `#cboxTitle`styles so it bumps to the top of the container and do the same for the remaining bottom elements `#cboxNext` etc.

Comment: Good answer. Question: What if you wanted to keep the title in the top and the paging at the bottom. I tried Adding margin-top:28px to cboxLoaded instead of replacing it, but the image moves down.